# SQL Database to Perl Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, perl, spreadsheet

I have a 'transaction' table created in SQL like this:

```
TranID  Date        AccNum   Type    Amount ChequeNo DDNo  
657520  02-07-1999  0181432  Debit   16000  465774     
657524  02-07-1999  0181432  Debit   13000           569086
657538  09-07-1999  0181432  Credit  11000  
657548  18-07-1999  0181432  Credit  15500  
657519  02-07-1999  0181432  Debit   12000  
657523  02-07-1999  0181432  Credit  11000  
657529  03-07-1999  0181433  Debit   15000  466777
657539  10-07-1999  0181433  Credit  10000  
657541  11-07-1999  0181433  Debit   12000  
657525  03-07-1999  0181433  Debit   15000           569999
657533  05-07-1999  0181433  Credit  12500
```

The question is: Query data from transaction table and calculate total amount debited by cheque, dd and by cash for each account and store the result in a spreadsheet. My script is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI; 
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:database:3306','prithvi','prithvi') or die $dbh->errstr;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `AccNum`,`Type`,`Amount`,`ChequeNo`,`DDNo` FROM `transaction`");
$sth->execute or die $sth->errstr;
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('query_result.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $row = 0;
my $col = 0;
my %h;
$worksheet->write_row($row++,$col,['Account Number','Cheque Debit','DD Debit','Cash Debit']);
while(my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array)
{
 next unless($data[1] eq 'Debit');
 my $result = $data[3] ? "ChequeNo" : $data[4] ? "DDNo" : "Cash";
 $h{$data[0]}{$result} += $data[2];
 $worksheet->write_row($row++,$col,\@data);
}
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

I am not getting the proper output. Where am I going wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance.
I have not got the answer for this question i.e., mainly storing the result in a spreadsheet. Please do not close this before answering. This is a very kind request to all of you.

Comment: Go over your previous questions and click the big tick next to the answers you used.

Comment: Here's how it is: You created a good overall post. There's example data, you've described the situation, you've showed code and that code even has `strict` and `warnings`. **But** there's no question in the post, and you want us to write complete code. That's not what we do here. We can help you if you run into problems, but SO is not a code writing service. Also, as @RobEarl said, you should accept answers in your previous questions, or no-one will help you.

Comment: Also, your output will be weird. It's not a spreadsheet, but rather:
`<td>Account</td><td>Number-Type-Total</td><td>Debit</td><td>Amount</td>`
`016901581432-Debit-29000`
... and so on. That's hardly a spreadsheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl Database script to Spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702857/perl-database-script-to-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT
    t1.AccountNumber, 
    SUM(t1.Amount)-(SELECT SUM(t2.Amount) from transaction t2 
     where t2.Type = 'Credit' 
     AND t2.AccountNumber = t1.AccountNumber) AS Subtraction
    from transaction t1
    WHERE t1.Type = 'Debit'
    group by t1.AccountNumber
```

Result:

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER   SUBTRACTION
016901581432    2500
016901581433    6000
016901581434    14500
```

**[SQLFIDDLE example edited.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9c53/14)**

Comment: Mr.Justin-How can I change your above query if I want to get the output for Debit-Credit amount(Subtraction) for each account?

Comment: I change my answer, now with Subtraction

Comment: Mark as answer, if this what you need:)

Comment: Sir.In the above query, isnt it possible to calculate and display only the account number and Subtraction column output using SQL query?

Comment: I got the answer required. But its the matter of displaying exactly in case of subtraction.Now I want to display only Account Number and Subtraction column using query.How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a good handle on how to interface to the database and write an SQL query.  Now you just need to get the results into a spreadsheet.

If you want an Excel spreadsheet, I suggest you look at the [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#SYNOPSIS) module.  I have used this in the past with good results.  Here is a brief example of how to use it:

```
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

#
#Query the database here...
#


my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('query_results.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

my $row = 0;
my $col = 0;

#Write the column labels.
$worksheet->write_row($row++, $col, 
    ['Account Number','Type','Total Debit Amount']
);

while( my @data = $tran_cur->fetchrow_array)
{
    #Write an array into a row in the spreadsheet.
    $worksheet->write_row($row++, $col, \@data);
}
```

If you don't want an Excel spreadsheet, try searching [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) for a module in the format you want, or use something like  [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) to create a CSV file that can easily be imported into any spreadsheet.

Comment: Oh.Thank you so much. I got the required output

Comment: I'm curious as to why this post was downvoted with no explanation.

Comment: If you can get away with writing Excel 2007+ XLSX files, I would recommend [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://p3rl.org/Excel::Writer::XLSX). over [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel).