# From Database in Perl to spreadsheet

Tags: perl

I have a transaction table like this:

```
TransactionID    Date           AccountNumber   Type    Amount  
657520           02-07-1999     016901581432    Debit   16000  
657524           02-07-1999     016901581432    Debit   13000  
657538           09-07-1999     016901581432    Credit  11000  
657548           18-07-1999     016901581432    Credit  15500  
657519           02-07-1999     016901581433    Debit   12000  
657523           02-07-1999     016901581433    Credit  11000  
657529           03-07-1999     016901581433    Debit   15000  
657539           10-07-1999     016901581433    Credit  10000  
657541           11-07-1999     016901581434    Debit   12000  
657525           03-07-1999     016901581434    Debit   15000  
657533           05-07-1999     016901581434    Credit  12500
```

I am supposed to find the total debit and total credit amount for each account using SQL query from the database and store result in spreadsheet using Perl.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:database','prithvi','prithvi') or die "Couldn't connect";
my $tran_cur = $dbh->prepare("SELECT AccountNumber, Type, SUM(Amount) FROM transaction GROUP BY AccountNumber, Type");
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('results.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('Result');
my $row = 0;
my $col = 0;
$worksheet->write_row($row++, $col, ['Account Number','Type','Total Amount']);
while( my @data = $tran_cur->fetchrow_array)
{
 $worksheet->write_row($row++, $col, \@data);
}
```

Where am I going wrong in the code? Please help. I get only the heading in the Excelsheet as the output.

Comment: Where is your `$tran_cur->execute`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the prepared statement before calling `$tran_cur->fetchrow_array`:

```
$tran_cur->execute;
```