# Perl Database script from table

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [From Database in Perl to spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756971/from-database-in-perl-to-spreadsheet)

I have a transaction table like this:

```
TranID  Date        AccNum   Type    Amount ChequeNo DDNo  
657520  02-07-1999  0181432  Debit   16000  465774     
657524  02-07-1999  0181432  Debit   13000           569086
657538  09-07-1999  0181432  Credit  11000  
657548  18-07-1999  0181432  Credit  15500  
657519  02-07-1999  0181432  Debit   12000  
657523  02-07-1999  0181432  Credit  11000  
657529  03-07-1999  0181433  Debit   15000  466777
657539  10-07-1999  0181433  Credit  10000  
657541  11-07-1999  0181433  Debit   12000  
657525  03-07-1999  0181433  Debit   15000           569999
657533  05-07-1999  0181433  Credit  12500
```

My question is:
Query the data from transaction table and calculate the total amount debited by cheque, dd and cash for each account.
My code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI; 

print "content-type:text/html\n\n";

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:database:3306','prithvi','prithvi') 
    or die "Couldn't connect";

my $tran_cur = $dbh->prepare("SQL Query");
$tran_cur->execute;

map { print "<td>$_</td>" } qw(AccountNumber-ChequeDebit-DDDebit-CashDebit);
print "<br/>";

while (my @data = $tran_cur->fetchrow_array()) {

    my $rec = join '-', @data;
    print "$rec<br/>";
}
$tran_cur->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this using Single SQL query:
I want the output as:

```
AccountNumber-ChequeDebit-DDDebit-CashDebit
0181432-16000-13000-12000
0181433-15000-15000-12000
```

Thanks in advance. Please help.

Comment: Its not the duplicate of other question. Question is different

Comment: Agreed: this is related to, but different from, SO 12756971.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

print "content-type:text/html\n\n";

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:database:3306','prithvi','prithvi')
    or die "Couldn't connect";

my $tran_cur = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT `AccNum`, `Amount`
    FROM `database`
    WHERE `Type` = 'Debit'
    ORDER BY `TranID`;
");
$tran_cur->execute;

print "<br>AccountNumber-ChequeDebit-DDDebit-CashDebit</br>\n";

my %h;

while (my @data = $tran_cur->fetchrow_array()) {
    if ($h{$data[0]}) {
        $h{$data[0]} .= "-$data[1]";
    }
    else {
        $h{$data[0]} = $data[1];
    }
}

$tran_cur->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;

foreach my $key (sort keys(%h)) {
    print "<td>$key" . "-" . $h{$key} . "</td>\n";
}
```

It's perfectible, but it works ;)

Comment: You should edit the script to fit your wanted reallife `HTML table`

Comment: What do you mean by that statement $h{$data[0]} .= "-$data[1]"; This statement is something new for me?

Comment: It's crucial : a `HASH` see http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perlhashes.php Callaed `associative array` : kind of array with some words as indices.

Comment: You should master data types, it's the requirement for a good start. I mean HASH, ARRAY, SCALAR...

Comment: @user1708526, Why did you unaccept the answer ?